# CRISPR/Cas9: How can inserted DNA be used as a donor for the homology-directed repair if Cas9 only creates blunt ends?

Tags: cell-biology, dna, crispr, cas9, dna-repair

The CRISPR/Cas9 method allows new genes to be inserted. After Cas9 cuts the Target-DNA, it can use a homologous piece of DNA as a donor template for homology-directed repair. But HDR only occurs when there are sticky ends, and Cas9's cuts end in blunt ends.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this Addgene blog](https://blog.addgene.org/crispr-101-homology-directed-repair):

> There are four different HDR pathways to repair DSBs. Here are  three
> central steps of the HDR pathways:
>
> 1. The 5’-ended DNA strand is resected at the break to create a 3’ overhang. This will serve as both a substrate for proteins required for strand invasion and a primer for DNA repair synthesis.
> 2. ...

Essentially, this resection process generates the required overhangs through partial degradation of one of the strands.

To understand the mechanism of resection a bit better, this is a good read:

> Huertas, Pablo. "DNA resection in eukaryotes: deciding how to fix the break." Nature structural & molecular biology 17.1 (2010): 11-16.